# How to calculate time to load a file into a application thorugh C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file

I have written a code in C++ to open a file in its default application like `.doc` in MS-Word now I want to calculate time to open a file into its application.

For that I need to know percentage of file loaded into that application. But from last 7 days I couldn't find any suitable solution. So can any one help me in solving this problem?

If i am using windows then can windows task manager help me to do this?

Comment: Thats hard because you're spawning other processes and there is no real way to "know" that an application has finished loading.  At least not in a general sense.

Comment: Hmmmm, just a random thought, but maybe you could close the application after opening it, and see when the process is dead? This might serve as a rough measure, and is relying on the program fully loading before being killed which might not be the case. It seems like the time is going to vary by application, so I'm not sure there'd be a general way to do it.

Comment: If i am using windows then can windows task manager help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not only impossible, it doesn't even make sense.

When you play an MP3 in WMP, it doesn't load the whole file into memory. Instead, it maps a little bit of the file at a time into memory so it can decode the MP3 on the fly as it's playing. (I suppose if you play the song all the way through, without stopping or skipping or fast forwarding or rewinding, it will eventually read every byte of the file, probably finishing a few seconds before the song is over, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.)

Likewise, Word doesn't read any entire .doc file into memory (unless it's very small). That's how it's able to edit gigantic files without using huge amounts of memory. (Again, if you page through the whole file, it will probably eventually read every byte—for that matter, it may eventually copy enough of the file into an autosave backup file that it no longer needs to look at the original—but again, I doubt that's what you're looking for.)

If you only care about certain specific applications, and those applications have a COM Automation interface (as both WMP and Word do), they may have methods or events that will tell you when they're done "loading" a file (meaning they've read enough of it to start playing/displaying/etc.), or when they've "finished" with a file (meaning moved on to the next track, or whatever), but there's no generic answer to that; different applications will have different Automation interfaces. (And, as a side note, you really don't want to do COM Automation from C++ unless you really have to; it's much easier from jscript, vbscript, or your favorite .NET language…)

Answer (score 0):

If the third party process does not signal that it has loaded something, e.g., through some output stream, one way will be to view the file handles being opened and closed by the processes. I presume this will be similar to how "task managers" like Process Explorer are able to view file handles of processes. However, if the process does not close the file handle once it is done "loading", then, you will not get an accurate time. Furthermore, you won't be able to get a "live" percentage of how much data has been loaded.